# Implementing a Slack-like Input Accessory

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create an InputAccessoryView/View pinned to the keyboard in SwiftUI with the following functionalities:

It should be pinned to the keyboard when it appears. Tapping the view should open the keyboard. When dragging the view down, it should expand vertically towards the navigation bar. While I've found some resources, I'm unsure about the best approach to achieve this.

code:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Text")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
        }
        ScrollView {
            
        }
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
        .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
        
        HStack {
            Button {
                // open attachment
            } label: {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                    Image(systemName: "paperclip")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
            
            TextField("Post to noticeboard", text: $messageText, axis: .vertical)
                .submitScope()
                .lineLimit(1...5)
                .padding()
                .onSubmit {
                    sendMessage(message: messageText)
                }
            
            Button {
                sendMessage(message: messageText)
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
            }
            .font(.system(size: 26))
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

func sendMessage(message: String) {
}

}
```

If you see the above code I have an HStack which consists of attachment button, TextView, and send button. This view should be expanded based on the gesture like Slack.

Could anyone provide insights or share code examples on how to implement this effectively using SwiftUI, potentially combining it with UIKit for keyboard management?

I have a reference of Slack app screenshot exactly as I should need to implement.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not really a Slack user to expand a view is quite simple in **SwiftUI** using `gestures`. I implemented a Drag Gesture that when the user swipes up (I know in your question you say "Drag down" but that seems unnatural to me) the `TextField` expands towards the Navigation Bar, and when you swipe down it returns towards the keyboard. You can invert the condition if you want the opposite behavior.

Here's the code **updated to be smoother**:

```
@State private var messageText = ""
@State private var expandTextField: Bool = false
@State private var textFieldOffset: CGFloat = .zero

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        let size = proxy.size
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Noticeboard")
                    .font(.title)
                    .bold()
            }
            ScrollView {
                
            }
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
            .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
            .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: expandTextField ? 20 : 0, style: .continuous))
            .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .bottom)
            .overlay(alignment: expandTextField ? .top : .bottom) {
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        // open attachment
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                            Image(systemName: "paperclip")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                    
                    TextField("Post to noticeboard", text: $messageText, axis: .vertical)
                        .submitScope()
                        .lineLimit(1...5)
                        .padding()
                        .onSubmit {
                            sendMessage(message: messageText)
                        }
                    
                    Button {
                        sendMessage(message: messageText)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 26))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .frame(height: expandTextField ? size.height : 60,
                       alignment: expandTextField ? .top : .center)
                .padding(.bottom)
                .padding()
                .offset(y: textFieldOffset)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            let translationY = value.translation.height
                            print(translationY)
                            
                            withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.3)) {
                                textFieldOffset = translationY
                            }
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            let translationY = value.translation.height
                            withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.5)) {
                                if translationY < -100 {
                                    expandTextField = true
                                } else if translationY > 100 {
                                    expandTextField = false
                                }
                                textFieldOffset = .zero
                            }
                        })
                    
                )
                .background(.red)
                .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: expandTextField ? 20 : 0, style: .continuous))
            }
            
        }
    }
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .bottom)
}

func sendMessage(message: String) {}
```

What I did was to use a **boolean** `State` variable that I update in the Gesture's `onChanged` callback. You can fine tune those values for your needs, of course.
I also took the chance to give **rounded corners** to the `ScrollView` like in the screenshots you provided when the TextField is up is up. If you always wish to have rounded corners you can remove the ternary condition there and replace it with just: `.clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous))`.
**Update:** I used the `smooth` animation to make it smoother and also made the TextField follow the user's finger to give it even a **smoother** look and feel.

Let me know your thoughts on this solution!

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your effort

Comment: If my solution helped consider marking it as correct, or at least upvoting if it did not solve your issue entirely.

Comment: i had upvoted your solution. and added a gif image for the clear undestanding the question

Comment: If you see the gif image the animation is smooth and clear but the code which you posted is not that smooth. hope you also had the same issue

Comment: Thanks. So, apart from what I've done you also would like the background to become darker? Or is there something more?

Comment: @Vignesh Ok, I'll try improving it.

Comment: @Vignesh take a look now. I've updated the code.

Comment: This looks good, we need to changes gesture on top as like slack. example right now the gesture works when i press between the TextField and button . instead of this we should the line on top of the textfield so that it can be easily draggable

Comment: the view is not getting expanding instead it's just moving. can you change the HStack background and see it

Comment: for better now. Thank you so much for your effort I surely accept this answer

Comment: If see the gif image on message to Jira text there will be a line vertically center that part is being dragged. can you please tell me how to add that and make that as draggable?

Comment: @Vignesh Just place the textField in a VStack and add a capsule with a small height before the TextField.

Comment: @Vignesh Mark my answer as correct now?

Comment: accepted the answer thank you.

Comment: please remove your demo gif image from the answer?

Comment: Yes, but why? If you can tell me.

Comment: This design should not be showcases.  Atleast change the title please

Comment: I am unable to set corner radius for the view when it's not editing